# Why is the password field cleared on error?

Tags: forms, symfony, validation

When there is an error in any field, the password and password confirmation fields are cleared, which is annoying for the user.

Is this by design? Why?

Comment: try http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/password.html#always-empty if you want the values be kept - but I cannot test it here now.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper could you answer this question yourself and mark it as 'accepted' after 24 hours?

Comment: @WouterJ Sure I'll do that if luiges doesn't. But I think it's 48 hs.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper ah, sorry. I didn't read luiges90 answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `always_empty` option to false.

http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/reference/forms/types/password.html#always-empty